# C# WPF filter items in Combobox based on text

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, combobox

I'm trying to build a commbobox filter, as described here:
http://andora.us/blog/2012/01/25/filtering-items-in-a-wpf-combobox/

I've followed the example as described here, but it doesn't work when I have multiple comboboxes in a window. If I apply a filter in one combobox, the same filter is applied in all other boxes. How do I set this up such that separate filters are used in each combobox?

Also - when I try to select one of the items in the filtered list, it doesn't always populate in comobobox.

Perhaps there is a different/better solution to this?

```
The first part of it was creating a new Style for the ComboBox, so that inside the Popup (PART_Popup) portion of the ControlTemplate can include my filtering TextBox.
```

```
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Margin="0,5,10,5" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="Filter:" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="DropDownFilterTextBox" />
                </DockPanel>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
```

The other piece of this is filtering the items in the within the ComboBox as they type in the filter TextBox.  To do this, I attach to the TextChanged event on it.

protected void DropDownFilterTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = ((TextBox)sender);

```
ComboBox cbo = ((TextBox)sender).TemplatedParent as ComboBox;
cbo.Items.Filter += a =>
{
    if (a.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(textBox.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

}

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: My Code is identical to that in the link - but I have copied and pasted into my question now so it is easier to see. Thanks.

Comment: You have set this in your template (which is missing on your question) and therefore you override all ComboBoxes

Comment: Yes, I have it set in my template and I want to overide all boxes.

Comment: Then you have to create a style overriding the default combobox and setting the template property. But this is not recommended as you might don't want one box to have this style